# Случайное положение дочерних елементов

Tags: jquery

Всем привет! Есть скрипт `<https://codepen.io/kotya_ra/pen/pojrNxN>` , дающий возможность зажиманием мышки передвигаться( скролить блок), и рандомно распологать дочерние элементы (img) в этом блоке. Как расположить дочерние элементы рандомно, но с расстоянием между ними? Исключить наложение друг на друга. Проблема на картинках :

Так на данный момент :

[image: Так на данный момент]

Так должно быть :

[image: Так должно быть]

Comment: Очень плохо, что на ходу меняете код по данной Вами ссылке. Сначала код дублировать нужно сюда, а в дополнение ссылку. Иначе, все ответы не будут соответствовать контексту. Ниже мой вариант ответа на "исходный код".

Answer (score 1):

Если "дёшево и сердито", то проще всего сделать так:

```js
(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(["exports"], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports !== "undefined") {
    factory(exports);
  } else {
    factory((root.dragscroll = {}));
  }
})(this, function(exports) {
  var _window = window;
  var _document = document;
  var mousemove = "mousemove";
  var mouseup = "mouseup";
  var mousedown = "mousedown";
  var EventListener = "EventListener";
  var addEventListener = "add" + EventListener;
  var removeEventListener = "remove" + EventListener;
  var newScrollX, newScrollY;

  var dragged = [];
  var reset = function(i, el) {
    for (i = 0; i < dragged.length;) {
      el = dragged[i++];
      el = el.container || el;
      el[removeEventListener](mousedown, el.md, 0);
      _window[removeEventListener](mouseup, el.mu, 0);
      _window[removeEventListener](mousemove, el.mm, 0);
    }

    // cloning into array since HTMLCollection is updated dynamically
    dragged = [].slice.call(_document.getElementsByClassName("dragscroll"));
    for (i = 0; i < dragged.length;) {
      (function(el, lastClientX, lastClientY, pushed, scroller, cont) {
        (cont = el.container || el)[addEventListener](
          mousedown,
          (cont.md = function(e) {
            if (!el.hasAttribute("nochilddrag") ||
              _document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY) == cont
            ) {
              pushed = 1;
              lastClientX = e.clientX;
              lastClientY = e.clientY;

              e.preventDefault();
            }
          }),
          0
        );

        _window[addEventListener](
          mouseup,
          (cont.mu = function() {
            pushed = 0;
          }),
          0
        );

        _window[addEventListener](
          mousemove,
          (cont.mm = function(e) {
            if (pushed) {
              (scroller = el.scroller || el).scrollLeft -= newScrollX = -lastClientX + (lastClientX = e.clientX);
              scroller.scrollTop -= newScrollY = -lastClientY + (lastClientY = e.clientY);
              if (el == _document.body) {
                (scroller = _document.documentElement).scrollLeft -= newScrollX;
                scroller.scrollTop -= newScrollY;
              }
            }
          }),
          0
        );
      })(dragged[i++]);
    }
  };

  if (_document.readyState == "complete") {
    reset();
  } else {
    _window[addEventListener]("load", reset, 0);
  }

  exports.reset = reset;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dragscroll img").each(function() {
    $(this).css({
      marginLeft: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
      marginTop: Math.floor(5 + Math.random() * 50),
      verticalAlign: ['baseline', 'bottom', 'middle', 'sub', 'super', 'text-bottom', 'text-top', 'top'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)]
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.dragscroll {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -o-grab;
  cursor: grab;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dragscroll">
  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">

</div>
```

Чтобы изображения не только псевдохаотично располагались, но и менялся их порядок, нужно добавить перемешивание полученной коллекции и замену элементов согласно новой очерёдности:

```js
(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(["exports"], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports !== "undefined") {
    factory(exports);
  } else {
    factory((root.dragscroll = {}));
  }
})(this, function(exports) {
  var _window = window;
  var _document = document;
  var mousemove = "mousemove";
  var mouseup = "mouseup";
  var mousedown = "mousedown";
  var EventListener = "EventListener";
  var addEventListener = "add" + EventListener;
  var removeEventListener = "remove" + EventListener;
  var newScrollX, newScrollY;

  var dragged = [];
  var reset = function(i, el) {
    for (i = 0; i < dragged.length;) {
      el = dragged[i++];
      el = el.container || el;
      el[removeEventListener](mousedown, el.md, 0);
      _window[removeEventListener](mouseup, el.mu, 0);
      _window[removeEventListener](mousemove, el.mm, 0);
    }

    // cloning into array since HTMLCollection is updated dynamically
    dragged = [].slice.call(_document.getElementsByClassName("dragscroll"));
    for (i = 0; i < dragged.length;) {
      (function(el, lastClientX, lastClientY, pushed, scroller, cont) {
        (cont = el.container || el)[addEventListener](
          mousedown,
          (cont.md = function(e) {
            if (!el.hasAttribute("nochilddrag") ||
              _document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY) == cont
            ) {
              pushed = 1;
              lastClientX = e.clientX;
              lastClientY = e.clientY;

              e.preventDefault();
            }
          }),
          0
        );

        _window[addEventListener](
          mouseup,
          (cont.mu = function() {
            pushed = 0;
          }),
          0
        );

        _window[addEventListener](
          mousemove,
          (cont.mm = function(e) {
            if (pushed) {
              (scroller = el.scroller || el).scrollLeft -= newScrollX = -lastClientX + (lastClientX = e.clientX);
              scroller.scrollTop -= newScrollY = -lastClientY + (lastClientY = e.clientY);
              if (el == _document.body) {
                (scroller = _document.documentElement).scrollLeft -= newScrollX;
                scroller.scrollTop -= newScrollY;
              }
            }
          }),
          0
        );
      })(dragged[i++]);
    }
  };

  if (_document.readyState == "complete") {
    reset();
  } else {
    _window[addEventListener]("load", reset, 0);
  }

  exports.reset = reset;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  let aIMGs = [...$(".dragscroll img")].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  $parent = $("div.dragscroll");
  aIMGs.forEach(function(el) {
    $(el).css({
      marginLeft: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
      marginTop: Math.floor(5 + Math.random() * 50),
      verticalAlign: ['baseline', 'bottom', 'middle', 'sub', 'super', 'text-bottom', 'text-top', 'top'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)]
    });
    $parent.append($(el));
  });
});
```

```css
.dragscroll {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -o-grab;
  cursor: grab;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dragscroll">
  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">

</div>
```

Развивая тему, можно (даже нужно) поместить изображения (вернее, ссылки на них) сразу в массив и на их основе заполнить контейнер (например, при динамическом изменении всё равно придётся к этому вернуться):

```js
(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(["exports"], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports !== "undefined") {
    factory(exports);
  } else {
    factory((root.dragscroll = {}));
  }
})(this, function(exports) {
  var _window = window;
  var _document = document;
  var mousemove = "mousemove";
  var mouseup = "mouseup";
  var mousedown = "mousedown";
  var EventListener = "EventListener";
  var addEventListener = "add" + EventListener;
  var removeEventListener = "remove" + EventListener;
  var newScrollX, newScrollY;

  var dragged = [];
  var reset = function(i, el) {
    for (i = 0; i < dragged.length;) {
      el = dragged[i++];
      el = el.container || el;
      el[removeEventListener](mousedown, el.md, 0);
      _window[removeEventListener](mouseup, el.mu, 0);
      _window[removeEventListener](mousemove, el.mm, 0);
    }

    // cloning into array since HTMLCollection is updated dynamically
    dragged = [].slice.call(_document.getElementsByClassName("dragscroll"));
    for (i = 0; i < dragged.length;) {
      (function(el, lastClientX, lastClientY, pushed, scroller, cont) {
        (cont = el.container || el)[addEventListener](
          mousedown,
          (cont.md = function(e) {
            if (!el.hasAttribute("nochilddrag") ||
              _document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY) == cont
            ) {
              pushed = 1;
              lastClientX = e.clientX;
              lastClientY = e.clientY;

              e.preventDefault();
            }
          }),
          0
        );

        _window[addEventListener](
          mouseup,
          (cont.mu = function() {
            pushed = 0;
          }),
          0
        );

        _window[addEventListener](
          mousemove,
          (cont.mm = function(e) {
            if (pushed) {
              (scroller = el.scroller || el).scrollLeft -= newScrollX = -lastClientX + (lastClientX = e.clientX);
              scroller.scrollTop -= newScrollY = -lastClientY + (lastClientY = e.clientY);
              if (el == _document.body) {
                (scroller = _document.documentElement).scrollLeft -= newScrollX;
                scroller.scrollTop -= newScrollY;
              }
            }
          }),
          0
        );
      })(dragged[i++]);
    }
  };

  if (_document.readyState == "complete") {
    reset();
  } else {
    _window[addEventListener]("load", reset, 0);
  }

  exports.reset = reset;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $parent = $("div.dragscroll");
  // Если требуется перемешать
  // aIMGs.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).forEach(function(el) {
  aIMGs.forEach(function(el) {
    let oImg = new Image();
    oImg.src = el;
    $(oImg).css({
      width: 200,
      height: 'auto',
      marginLeft: Math.floor(5 + Math.random() * 50),
      marginTop: Math.floor(5 + Math.random() * 50),
      verticalAlign: ['baseline', 'bottom', 'middle', 'sub', 'super', 'text-bottom', 'text-top', 'top'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)]
    });
    $parent.append($(oImg));
  });
});

let aIMGs = ["https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg","https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png","https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg","https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg","https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg","https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png","https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg","https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg","https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg","https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png","https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg","https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg","https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg","https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png","https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg","https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg","https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg","https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png","https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg","https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg","https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/83D7/production/_111515733_gettyimages-1208779325.jpg","https://sjferret.com/wp-content/uploads/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png","https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg","https://www.interfax.ru/ftproot/textphotos/2019/05/17/700gc.jpg"];
```

```css
.dragscroll {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -o-grab;
  cursor: grab;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dragscroll"></div>
```